# Drupal 8 Multi step Login Form

Tags: drupal, authentication, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I need to make the login page as below in Drupal 8.

http://i84.servimg.com/u/f84/18/45/41/65/login_10.gif

Kindly let me know is there any module existing for this or how I can approach this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same i need for Drupal 7 as well, kindly suggest me

Answer (score 0):

You want to build a multistep form, so may have a look on How to Build Multi-step Forms in Drupal 8 There will be values from the first form used in the second form.  https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-multi-step-forms-in-drupal-8/

Answer (score 0):

There is now a module (for D9 & D10) for this functionality:
https://www.drupal.org/project/mutli_step_login

I cannot vouch for it because I found it with the same web search as I found this question.